# Image and preimage of a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions

> Given the function $f(x)=x^{2}-4x-5$, $A=[0,3)$ and $B=[0,1]$, find $f(A)$ and $f^{-1}(B)$.

I found $f(A)$ by looking at the graph $f([0,3))=[-9,-5]$  but how would I calculate this without the graph? If I plug in $0$ into $f$ I get $-5$, and if I plug in $3$ I get $-8$, when I should get $-9$.

Comment: Are you asking about $f^{-1}(B)$ too?

Comment: Hint: Use the derivative to find where this function is increasing or decreasing.

Comment: Use f'(x)=2x-4=0 when x=2 and f''(x)=2>0. to notice that f has a minimum at f (2)=-9.  That f (x) > 0 for x >2 so is increasing for x >2 and f'(x)< 0 for x <2.  f is contionuous.  So f (0,1]) = [f (1),f (0)].  [0,3) will contain the minimum so f ([0,3)) will be [f (2), max (f (0),f (3)).

Comment: Of, f inverse.  Just solve for f(x)=0 and f (x)=1.  Then f (B) will be between those points, (unless the min is in there too).

Comment: If the function is continuous then you only need the absolute maximum and absolute minimum in the domain of the function to know the image of the function, i.e. the image of the function goes from the minimum to the maximum, it is the interval $(\min f(x),\max f(x))$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=x^2-4x-5=(x-2)^2-9$$
The vertex of $f$ lies at $(2,-9)$ and 2 lies in $[0,3)$, so $f[A]$ has a closed lower endpoint at $-9$. 0 is farther from 2 than 3 is, so $f(0)=-5$ constitutes the upper endpoint, which is also closed. Hence $f[A]=[-9,-5]$.

As for $f^{-1}[B]$, solve for the places where $f(x)$ attains the endpoint values of $B$:
$$f(x)=0\text{ when }x=-1\text{ or }x=5$$
$$f(x)=1\text{ when }x=2\pm\sqrt{10}$$
Since $f(x)$ is decreasing when $x<2$ and increasing when $x>2$, we get
$$f^{-1}[B]=[2-\sqrt{10},-1]\cup[5,2+\sqrt{10}]$$

Answer (score 2):

More general if $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f(x) = ax^2 + bx + c, a \gt 0$ then $f$ is decreasing on $(-\infty, - \frac b {2a}]$ and increasing on $[- \frac b {2a}, + \infty)$. You can use this together with the fact that $f$ is continuous to get the images you want.

Comment: We can get even more general with f (x) continuous and solving f'(x)=0.